# Remove line skip in itemize when using displaystyle

Tags: align, enumerate

When I use "enumerate" environment with "align*", the code skips a line. Is there a way to make the first line to be moved up in the same line as 1.?
Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{align*}
x^3 &=x^2 + 1\\
x^3 - x^2 - 1&= 0
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

Do not use `align*` use `$\begin{aligned}[t]`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
$\begin{aligned}[t]
x^3 &=x^2 + 1\\
x^3 - x^2 - 1&= 0
\end{aligned}$
\item
\hspace*{\fill}%
$\begin{aligned}[t]
x^3 &=x^2 + 1\\
x^3 - x^2 - 1&= 0
\end{aligned}$%
\hspace*{\fill}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```